# SQL statement count all items per order, display itemid, orderid and itemNumber

Tags: sql, t-sql

First, thanks for your time and your help!

I have one single table with "product_ID" and "order_ID".

One Order has 0 or multiple(n) products.

"product_ID" is unique, because each product has its own barcode.

```
|      product_ID     |     order_ID     |
+---------------------+------------------+
|          p1         |        o1        |
|          p2         |        o1        |
|          p3         |        o2        |
|          p4         |        o3        |
|          p5         |        o2        |
|          p6         |        o4        |
|          p7         |        o1        |
```

My problem is the following: I want to count how often one order occurs and display the number in one additional column.

I have tried it for about 2 days, but I cannot seem to solve this problem.

One of my attempts with T-SQL, but suggestions of other SQL versions are also appreciated:

```
SELECT 
    order_ID, COUNT(order_ID) as 'product_COUNT'
FROM  
    product_table
GROUP BY 
    order_ID

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    product_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    product_table
GROUP BY 
    product_ID
```

The result should look like this:

```
|      product_ID     |     Order_ID     |   product_Count  |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|          p1         |        o1        |        3         |
|          p2         |        o1        |        3         |
|          p3         |        o2        |        2         |
|          p4         |        o3        |        1         |
|          p5         |        o2        |        2         |
|          p6         |        o4        |        1         |
|          p7         |        o1        |        3         |
```

Comment: So the same product can't be in several orders?

Comment: yes, because in this table every product has a barcode that is unique . the product_ID is just an abstraction for the barcode.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want window functions:

```
select po.*, count(*) over (partition by order_id) as product_count
from single_table po;
```

Your sample query has aggregation, but that doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: looks great, i will try it right know . Thanks for the fast answer :)

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP, it works ! Never heard about this, now i can die happy :D.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, without using window functions

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (product_ID VARCHAR(5), order_ID  VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
('p1', 'o1'),
('p2', 'o1'),
('p3', 'o2'),
('p4', 'o3'),
('p5', 'o2'),
('p6', 'o4'),
('p7', 'o1')

SELECT T.*, T1.product_Count FROM @MyTable T
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT order_ID, COUNT(*) product_Count FROM @MyTable GROUP BY order_ID) T1 ON T.order_ID = T1.order_ID
```

Result:

```
product_ID order_ID product_Count
---------- -------- -------------
p1         o1       3
p2         o1       3
p3         o2       2
p4         o3       1
p5         o2       2
p6         o4       1
p7         o1       3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :D, i cant believe that i am getting this so fast.